# Cloud Build, Container Registry, Cloud Run: Run tests without exposing env var

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-secret-manager

Cloud build do the following:

1. Build image from dockerfile (see dockerfile below)
2. Push image to container registry
3. Update service in Cloud Run

My issue is the following:

As I'm running my tests on build time, I need my `MONGODB_URI` secret on build time, but I've read that using `--build-arg` is not safe to expose secrets.

I could run `npm install` and `npm run test` in Cloud Build container, but it would make build time longer as I'll have to run npm install two times.

Is there a way I can run only once npm install without having to expose secrets ?

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16
COPY . ./
WORKDIR /
RUN npm install 

ARG env
ARG mongodb_uri

ENV ENVIRONMENT=$env
ENV DB_REMOTE_PROD=$mongodb_uri

RUN npm run test
RUN npm run build
CMD ["node", "./build/index.js"]
```

And my cloudbuild.yaml config:

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - '-c'
      - >-
        docker build --no-cache -t
        $_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
        --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=staging --build-arg mongodb_uri=$$MONGODB_URI -f
        Dockerfile .
    id: Build
    entrypoint: bash
    secretEnv:
      - MONGODB_URI
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - push
      - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
    id: Push
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - >-
        gcloud run services update $_SERVICE_NAME --platform=managed
        --image=$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
        --labels=managed-by=gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run,commit-sha=$COMMIT_SHA,gcb-build-id=$BUILD_ID,gcb-trigger-id=$_TRIGGER_ID
        --region=$_DEPLOY_REGION --update-env-vars=ENVIRONMENT=staging
        --update-env-vars=DB_REMOTE_PROD=$$MONGODB_URI --quiet
    id: Deploy
    entrypoint: bash
    secretEnv:
      - MONGODB_URI
images:
  - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
options:
  substitutionOption: ALLOW_LOOSE
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
substitutions:
  _TRIGGER_ID: 44b16efe-0219-41af-b32b-9b98438728c3
  _GCR_HOSTNAME: eu.gcr.io
  _PLATFORM: managed
  _SERVICE_NAME: app-staging
  _DEPLOY_REGION: europe-southwest1
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - versionName: projects/PROJECT_ID/secrets/mongodb_app_staging/versions/1
      env: MONGODB_URI
```

With my method, the secret is exposed not only in the container since I pass it as build-args, but it is also exposed to all users with access to cloud run...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container build step is not so bad. You provide your secrets to your container, but it is not visible. It's only reference.

You can hardly do better. A solution could be to perform the secret access directly inside the Dockerfile, but I'm not sure that the "security gain" worth the Dockerfile increased complexity. *(If you want more details, let me know, I will be able to share sample)*

---

About Cloud Run, you are totally true: exposing secret in plain text in environment variable is totally not acceptable.

For that, you can use the [Cloud Run - Secret Manager integration](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/secrets#command-line). Instead of doing this

```
gcloud run services update $_SERVICE_NAME --platform=managed
        --image=$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
        --labels=managed-by=gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run,commit-sha=$COMMIT_SHA,gcb-build-id=$BUILD_ID,gcb-trigger-id=$_TRIGGER_ID
        --region=$_DEPLOY_REGION --update-env-vars=ENVIRONMENT=staging
        --update-env-vars=DB_REMOTE_PROD=$$MONGODB_URI --quiet
```

You can do that (and you now longer need to set the secret as env var of your Cloud Build step)

```
gcloud run services update $_SERVICE_NAME --platform=managed
        --image=$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
        --labels=managed-by=gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run,commit-sha=$COMMIT_SHA,gcb-build-id=$BUILD_ID,gcb-trigger-id=$_TRIGGER_ID
        --region=$_DEPLOY_REGION --update-env-vars=ENVIRONMENT=staging
        --update-secrets=DB_REMOTE_PROD=mongodb_app_staging:1 --quiet
```

Comment: Thank you, I just switched to --update-secrets instead.
So just to be sure, refering to $$MONGODB_URI as build arguments in my build step isn't a security issue ?

Comment: It will become a security issue if the secret is displayed in plain text. AFAIK, there is no log, no print of its content. However, I had another look on your Dockerfile and if it's the whole file, I think the secret value is in plain text inside your container (kept in the ENV step). Keep in mind that a container is just a way to package an app, like a ZIP or a JAR, it's not unbreakable or encrypted!